# Does Mass Effect 3 track single-player statistics?

Tags: mass-effect-3

There are a few games out there that summarize your single-player performance at certain intervals or at the end of the game. I'm referring to stats like accuracy, headshots, damage, mission completion time, etc.

**Does Mass Effect 3 keep track of any of these player statistics and display them at some point during the game? If so, what does it track and when does it display the numbers?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a way it keeps stats across single and multiplayer for your achievements. Your achievements count kills/upgrades/ect made across all Careers and multiplayer characters. For instance, burning 10 enemies in Single player and 10 more in Multiplayer gives you 20/100 progress for the Pyromaniac achievement.

However, there is no (displayed) counter of your stats other than that. There's no screen showing you your total kill count ect in any way I've seen.

Answer (score 0):

After finishing it, I've seen no such stats anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

No stats, just achievements based on stats and "medals" awarded ,based on stats, in MP.